# Get full value from editable content div

Tags: javascript, html, forms, contenteditable

I have a content editable div like this

`<div id="editablecontent" contenteditable="true" >This <span class="redtext">is</span> a test</div>`

When I use `document.getElementById(editablecontent).textContent`

Actual return `This is a test`

Expected return `This <span class="redtext">is</span> a test`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property:

```js
document.getElementById('editablecontent').innerHTML
```